# So user created when using Google Signin with AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I am learning about AWS concepts, and want to deploy a complete serverless application.

Using the [awsmobile tutorial](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/quick_start), I have been able to deploy a very crude react app with user signup and signin ([available here](http://notesreact-hosting-mobilehub-1918551287.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/)).

I see that by adding Google as a federated entity I can also enable Google Signin in the app.

My app, however, will only be relevant for Google user. As such, I want to **only allow Google Sign-up (creating users) and Sign-In (logging existing users in)**.

When signing in using Google in the application, I see that no user is created in the Cognito database, nor in the dynamodb. Is that expected?

I would expect the user to be available.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely possible. Best thing to do is have a go and come back if you get stuck. If you only want Google (or other 3rd party provider) sign-in, you can get away with not even having a user pool.

Comment: Well, I actually do have a start here : http://notesreact-hosting-mobilehub-1918551287.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ :). But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to remove the manual signup and only leave the Google version on the website. It also looks like sign in via Google Works for new users, but does not create users in the user pool.

Comment: Alright, I realize that my question is confusing. I will reformulate it :).

Comment: Did you solve the problem @jlengrand

Comment: I do not remember it's been a while ago! Now for all authentication things I use Firebase. (https://lengrand.fr/using-firebase-in-elm/)